# Add a column in SQL based on a threshold and time

Tags: python, sqlite, time-series

I have the data table below:

```
Vessel      DateStamp        Position   Capacity (%)    Destination
ALPHA     2016-07-17 09:51:00   P           30              A
BETA      2016-07-17 09:51:00   Q           75              B
GAMMA     2016-07-17 09:51:00   R           78              C
ALPHA     2016-07-16 09:51:16   S           30              D
BETA      2016-07-16 09:51:16   T           75              E
GAMMA     2016-07-16 09:51:16   U           78              F
ALPHA     2016-07-15 09:51:10   V           30              G
BETA      2016-07-15 09:51:10   W           40              H
GAMMA     2016-07-15 09:51:10   X           78              I
```

This may sound weird but:

I want to be able to add another column called 'Origin' based on at what point in the 'position' column the corresponding value in the 'capacity' column moves above '70%'

Hence Ship GAMMA would have an origin of 'X'
Ship BETA would have an Origin of 'T'
and Ship ALPHA would not have an origin

The actual origin is the location where the capacity changes from below 70% to above 70%

This would have to be chronological time dependent. As if a ship were going into a port empty loading up with 'goods' to above 70% then going on to the destination

I hope this is clear. I can answer any questions as necessary

Many thanks

Comment: The Gamma value never moves; why should it be X?

Comment: Hi CL. I was trying to demonstrate that ships where capacity start at or above 70% would have the first position as an origin

Comment: But the first position is not X.

Comment: The first position is X, it starts on 15th July 2016 and goes to 17 July 2016. Works from the bottom top the top so each day a new position will be added to the top of the list

Comment: Oops, I only looked at the times …

Comment: What if the capacity moves above 70% multiple times?

Comment: The way the loading works, it shouldn't happen, but if it did to take the most recent time it did move above 70%

Comment: What do you mean with "add another column"? Do you want to change the database table, or the result of the query, or do you want to be able to compute the origin for one specific vessel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution above is probably good but haven't looked at it yet.    Here's mine, which is potentially over-complex.

Firstly, you've tagged it as Python but question doesn't contain any python.  I will treat it as an SQL issue.

It seems like your adding a "summary" column to your non-summary table.  I.e. Vessel BETA has 1 Origin value but that table shows several records for BETA, some of them unrelated to that particular origin. This is fine but it just involves a bit of "twisting" hence the silly amount of joins you'll see below

Let's say that the above example data comes from the following query

```
SELECT Vessel, DateStamp, Position, Capacity, Destination FROM VESSEL_POSITIONS ORDER BY DateStamp DESC
```

Then you could do the following query

```
SELECT Vessel, MIN(DateStamp) AS DateStamp FROM VESSEL_POSITIONS WHERE Capacity > 70 GROUP BY Vessel
```

which will give you the earliest time for each Vessel when capacity is over 70 (not sure if thats what you want)
Vessels who's capacity doesn't go over 70 don't show up here.

Then you can do an INNER JOIN as follows

```
SELECT pos.Vessel AS Vessel, pos.Position AS Origin FROM VESSEL_POSITIONS pos 
INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT Vessel, MIN(DateStamp) AS DateStamp FROM VESSEL_POSITIONS WHERE Capacity > 70 GROUP BY Vessel) dat 
ON pos.Vessel = dat.Vessel and pos.DateStamp = dat.DateStamp)
```

which will give you the positions of those vessels at those times, labelled as Origin.

Then you join that to the original query with an OUTER JOIN to get the additional Origin column,  Vessels which never had a capacity over 70% will show up as null

```
SELECT p.Vessel, p.DateStamp, p.Position, p.Capacity, p.Destination, o.Origin FROM VESSEL_POSITIONS 
OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT pos.Vessel AS Vessel, pos.Position AS Origin FROM VESSEL_POSITIONS pos 
    INNER JOIN  
        (SELECT Vessel, MIN(DateStamp) AS DateStamp FROM VESSEL_POSITIONS WHERE Capacity > 70 GROUP BY Vessel) dat 
    ON pos.Vessel = dat.Vessel and pos.DateStamp = dat.DateStamp)) o
ON p.Vessel = o.Vessel
ORDER BY DateStamp DESC
```

Which should give you the same table as the one you posted but with the additional column

```
**Origin**
null
T
X
null
T
X
null
T
X
```

Answer (score 1):

For a ship, you want to retrieve the value in the `Position` column of a row for the same ship where the capacity is above 70%, and where the capacity of the previous row (if it exists) for the same ship is not above 70%.

In SQL:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET Origin = (SELECT Position
              FROM MyTable AS T2
              WHERE T2.Vessel = MyTable.Vessel
                AND T2.Capacity >= 70
                AND ifnull((SELECT Capacity
                            FROM MyTable AS T3
                            WHERE T3.Vessel = T2.Vessel
                              AND T3.DateStamp < T2.DateStamp
                            ORDER BY DateStamp DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                           ), 0) < 70);
```

Comment: The logic is perfect, thanks, but i'm trying to manipulate the data in python so then I can view it via a SQL interface

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to translate this